# Определение в дистантном положении

Tags: обособление

В Германии украдена историческая дверь на входе в бывший нацистский концентрационный лагерь Дахау высотой 190 и длиной 95 сантиметров, на которой была выведена известная циничная надпись "Arbeit macht frei" ("Труд освобождает").

Обязательно ли несогласованное определение *высотой 190 и длиной 95 сантиметров* обособлять?

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Это не уточнение (нет сужения смысла), несогласованное определение обособляется именно по причине дистантного положения, чтобы отделить от слов "лагерь Дахау", не отнести к нему. Запятая обязательна.

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая нужна, т.к. - это уточнение.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза не задалась, что называется. Смысл сообщения совсем не в размерах (да и в них-то сумятица: длина двери - нонсенс). Оттого и трудности.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется,что размеры лучше заключить в скобки, так как это дополнительные сведения, которые нет смысла выносить на первый план.